# Не устанавливается на Windows Slate Shopify

Tags: node.js, npm, install

Нужно установить Slate Shopify на Windows

npm:

> 6.9.0
>   yarn:
>   1.17.3
>   gulp:
>   CLI version: 2.2.0 Local version: 4.0.2

Делаю это командой:

> npm install -g @shopify/slate

Но при установки выбивает такой текст:

> npm WARN deprecated natives@1.1.6: This module relies on Node.js's internals and will break at some point. Do not use it, and update to graceful-fs@4.x. C:\Users\Marshall\AppData\Roaming\npm\slate -> C:\Users\Marshall\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@shopify\slate\lib\index.js + @shopify/slate@0.14.0 removed 658 packages and updated 1 package in 67.394s

Подскажите, что нужно исправить?. Как грамотно установить Slate Shopify под Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не используйте Slate. Он Deprecated c Января 2020
Рекомендую ThemeKit и собственная сборка Webpack или Gulp.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Команда уже переходит на ThemeKit